# css issue text keep moving outside of column and header does not remain in place on scroll

Tags: css

I have a css issue. As you can see in the sample below, I have a gray sidebar and a navbar. The sidebar is fixed, but I need the navbar to remain in place when the page scrolls. When I add fixed to that class, it breaks. How can I solve this issue? I also do not like that the text in the column with the paragraphs moves outside of the column when the screen resizes. How do I make the text remain inside its column on screen sizing?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Buttons Checkbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill"></script>


    <style>


      
              #sidebar {
                  min-width: 250px;
              }
      
         
      
              .container {
                  width: 500px;
                  margin: 0px auto 0;
                  float: right;
              }
      
        
      
              .site-header {
                  /*width: 300px;*/
                  min-width: 400px;
                  height: 1000px;
                  background-color: gainsboro;
                  position: fixed;
              }
 

    </style>
</head>
<body>
 
      
<div id="app" class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="" href="#">
                 
                  my title
                </a>
        
           
                  
            
            </nav>

            <div class="row" style="max-width: 100%;">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                        <header class="site-header">
                          
                        </header>
                    </div>


 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">    
      <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>\
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>






</div>







  
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/dashboard/ Try and take a look at bootstraps example, you might find some useful tips

Answer (score 0):

Add class with these properties to nav bar..this would help

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: Bootstrap has the `fixed-top` class which does this, that can be applied to the navbar

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap's built-in classes to achieve your result. If you don't want to, you need to use `position:fixed` on your sidebar. If you're using bootstrap, chances are that you really don't need to redefine containers unless there's a really good reason to.

I've amalgamated your problem with bootstrap's dashboard code. Here's the result I think you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/6amht57u/9/

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated code:

```
.site-header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    position: fixed;
}
.nav-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 991;
}
```

jQuery for scroll function:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if(windowWidth >= 768 && scroll >= 120) {
$(".navbar").addClass("nav-fixed");
} 
else {
$(".navbar").removeClass("nav-fixed");
}
});
```

For site-header its better you add width by calulating its parent width using jQuery